# pass textbox value to sql query c# application

Tags: c#, sql

I have a query how do I pass the textbox value to the query

- when I enter in textbox1 = PERSONDETAILS
- when I enter in textbox2 = HR

then this query should be executed

```
SELECT 
    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT', 'PERSONSDETAILS', 'HR') 
FROM 
    user_tables 
WHERE 
    ROWNUM = 1
```

In the above query, how do I pass the textbox1 and textbox2 in query in place of `PERSONDETAILS`, `HR`?

I did like this but not working please suggest me

```
SELECT 
    DBMS_METADATA.GET_DEPENDENT_DDL('OBJECT_GRANT',' + textbox1.Text + ',' + textbox2.Text + ') 
FROM 
    user_tables 
WHERE
    ROWNUM = 1
```

Comment: Where is the C# code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String sql = "SELECT progress  FROM dbo.progress  " +
                    " where id=@id";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
```

Here is my code sample.Ihave a method `public int SelectProgress(string id)` which the string id I take it from windows form textbox. And the i call the method `SelectProgress(textBox1.Text)`